# Graph API Retire Device

Tags: powershell, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retire a device that exists in Endpoint Manager using the Graph API with Powershell. I have been following the Microsoft documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-retire?view=graph-rest-1.0) but keep running into the same obscure error. Using Powershell, the commands I am running are as follows:

```
$Params = @{
    Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/$Id/retire"
    Method = 'Post'
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
    }
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

The $Id variable in the Uri is the ID of the device (the id field, not the deviceId). I have also tried it following the example in the documentation with the following Uri of
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userId/managedDevices/$Id/retire` which produced a different error.

One thing to note is that in Azure we have Application permission enabled for `DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All`, but the documentation says it should be `DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperation.All` (with no S after Operation). We are unsure if this is a typo, but we are unable to grant permission to `DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperation.All`.

Here is the error message for the first API call without users, with x's over the ID:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"_version\": 3,\r\n  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: db8fd35f-8bb9-4f36-ac0e-1427d1f95f7f - Url: https://fef.msua04.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices%28%27xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx%xx%xx/microsoft.management.services.api.remoteLock?api-version=2021-04-07\",\r\n  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",\r\n  \"RetryAfter\": null,\r\n  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",\r\n  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"\r\n}","innerError":{"date":"2022-05-10T21:18:50","request-id":"db8fd35f-8bb9-4f36-ac0e-1427d1f95f7f","client-request-id":"db8fd35f-8bb9-4f36-ac0e-1427d1f95f7f"}}}
```

The error message for the second call with Users in the Uri is:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"No method match route template","message":"No OData route exists that match template ~/entityset/key/navigation/key/action with http verb POST for request /DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/users('xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx')/managedDevices('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')/microsoft.management.services.api.retire.","innerError":{"date":"2022-05-10T20:48:21","request-id":"335505da-6996-4aff-a084-ff5ea780c285","client-request-id":"335505da-6996-4aff-a084-ff5ea780c285"}}}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess that PrivilegedOperation permission is typo in documentation. I've checked the permissions in Graph Explorer and here are both permissions DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperation.All and DeviceManagementManagedDevices.PrivilegedOperations.All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined we were using the incorrect Id. We were initially using the Id field from the Uri `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$email/ownedDevices`, which returned the incorrect Id. We should have been using the Id from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$email/managedDevices`. Using that Id with the retire command worked successfully.